# How do i locate Facebook's birthdate element with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to extract birthdate with Selenium (java & chrome) from 'about page' on Facebook's profile. How should I do it?

On Facebook 'about' tab there is an element that contains person's birthdate (if disclosed). I really would like to have it as a String. 
Example here: 
https://www.facebook.com/zuck/about?lst=100002006436635%3A4%3A1570508289

I've tried driver.findElementByXPath and driver.findElementByClassName as well as PartialLinkText. I've done this before in a different place and it worked, maybe I'm just doing something wrong here.

XPath code I've tried is here:

```
.findElementByXPath("//*[@class='_4bl9 _2pis _2dbl']");

.findElementByXPath("//*[contains(text(), 'birthdate')]");
```

Please guide me how should I locate this element or extract the birthdate

Comment: Where is date of birth field ? Please navigate us.

Comment: @cruisepandey It's right on the right side of this 'about' panel. I can't paste the source in the comment but Ayaz provided it in his answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  this xpath and let me know

```
//span[text()='Birthday']//../following-sibling::div
```

Example code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./libs/chromedriver 4");
         WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/zuck/about?lst=100002006436635%3A4%3A1570508289");
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("<username>");
        driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("<password>");
        driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).submit();
        driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("<password>");
        driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).submit();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/zuck/about?lst=100002006436635%3A4%3A1570508289");
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Birthday']//../following-sibling::div")).getText());

    }

}
```

### output

> 14 May 1984

Comment: Unfortunately I get NoSuchElementException

Comment: It works! Could you maybe explain why my simpler xPath didn't work?

Comment: Alright, I've figured out that it has something to do with the link - when I use link from clicking on the "about" tab with selenium - this xPath doesn't work
When using link from your code - it does. I have no idea why

Comment: Okay I got it! 
I was performing it with a click - the Birthday pane was taking a little bit longer to load - that's why I couldn't get this element located.
With link provided and using driver.get() the driver was waiting for the page to load before proceeding to locating the element. All my xPaths didn't find the Birthday data because it wasn't yet loaded to the page. A rookie mistake, but at least I learned something today. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with following xpath:

```
.//*[text()='Birthday']/parent::div/following-sibling::div
```

Below is the html I copied from the link you shared

```
<span class="_c24 _2ieq">
    <div>
        <span class="accessible_elem">Birthday</span>
    </div>
    <div>May 14, 1984</div>
</span>
```

Explanation:

`.//*[text()='Birthday']` will locate the Birthday span

`/parent::div` will locate the parent div

`following-sibling::div` will locate the div which contains DOB

you can then get the string value by either `getText()` or `getAttribute("innerText")` methods

Comment: Does it work for you? In my language version everything is the same besides 'Birthday' which is 'Data urodzenia'
I used xpath you provided with this slight change
    findElementByXPath(".//*[text()='Data urodzenia']/parent::div/following-sibling::div");
I get No Such Element Exception

Comment: Alright, mine didn't work for a different reason - I didn't wait for the page to load. Thank you very much

Comment: I am afraid text might change depending on the language. In that case this should work  .//span[@class='accessible_elem']/parent::div/following-sibling::div